# Replace awk in this command

Tags: linux, debian, sed, debian-installer, preseed

I am struggling with a preseed-script for Debian and figured out that awk is not available in the installation process.

### A little context

The preseed-script fails at the following line and returns empty result:

```
real=`ip -o link | awk '/<%= @host.mac -%>/ {print $2;}' | sed s/://`
cat << EOF > /etc/network/interfaces
#loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#<%= @host.primary_interface.identifier %>
auto $real
allow-hotplug $real
iface $real inet <%= host_dhcp ? 'dhcp' : 'static' %>
```

As result, `$real` is empty and produces a faulty network configuration.

### What I hope to archive

I'd like to rewrite the command so that the result looks like `ens18` or `eth0` based on this input:

```
root@vm:~# ip -o link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether 1e:7d:da:55:31:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This is the command which is failing during installation:

```
root@vm:~# ip -o link | awk '/1e:7d:da:55:31:23/ {print $2;}' | sed s/://
ens18
```

### My question

How can I avoid `awk` and work with other tools in this situation to get the interface-name like `ens18` from `ip -o link`-output? Unfortunately I am not that familiar with `sed`.

Comment: It's not clear why the `awk` command fails? After all it is essentially grepping only.....

Comment: awk seems just not to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `grep` and `cut`:

```
ip -o link | grep '1e:7d:da:55:31:23' | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed s/://
```